# Overwriting the Eloquent user provider throws an error

Tags: laravel-10

The provided code snippets suggest that you're extending the Eloquent user provider to override the validateCredentials function in order to modify the "password" field to "user_password". However, you're encountering an error.

**This error:**

```
TypeError: App\Providers\AuthUserProvider::__construct(): Argument #1 ($hasher) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher, Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in /var/www/apirenatre-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 849 in file /var/www/apirenatre-laravel/app/Providers/AuthUserProvider.php on line 13
```

Let's examine the provided files:

**App\Providers\AuthUserProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

class AuthUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    protected $hasher;

    public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model)
    {   
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
        parent::__construct($hasher, $model);
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        if (is_null($plain = $credentials['user_password'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
}
```

**App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...

    public function boot(): void
    {
        Auth::provider('auth_user_provider_custom', function($app, array $config) {
            return new AuthUserProvider($app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher::class), $config['model']);
        });
    }
}
```

**App\config.php**

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user_provider_custom',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'user_provider_custom' => [
            'driver' => 'auth_user_provider_custom',
            'table' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    | The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
    | generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
    | quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**App\Models\User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $connection = 'renatre';

    protected $table = 'app_fiscalizacion.users'; 

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    const UPDATED_AT = 'user_updated_at';

    const CREATED_AT = 'user_created_at';

    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_username',
        'user_password',
        'user_updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'user_password',
        'user_remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Given the provided code, it appears that you're extending the Eloquent user provider correctly, and you're registering it within the AuthServiceProvider. However, the error you're encountering isn't evident from the provided snippets.

Could you please provide more details about the error message you're receiving? This will help in diagnosing the issue effectively.

**This error:**

```
TypeError: App\Providers\AuthUserProvider::__construct(): Argument #1 ($hasher) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher, Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in /var/www/apirenatre-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 849 in file /var/www/apirenatre-laravel/app/Providers/AuthUserProvider.php on line 13
```